# Async operation in Startup (sample case: async AddJwtBearer)

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I have a .net core 3.1 app which uses our custom JWT token for authentication. In order to setup token validation, I need to fetch token signing certificates from KeyVault, which is an asynchronious operation:

```
services
  .AddAuthentication()
  .AddJwtBearer(DomainConstants.MyAuthenticationScheme, async options =>
    {
       var keys = await secretManager.GetKeys();
       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
          IssuerSigningKeys = keys,
          ...
        }
     });
```

I found out that AddJwtBearer is called on the first request, and it does not wait for the async operation to finish, because it's in fact an async void (see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20799).
This leads to the fact that first call returns Unauthorized. 2nd call works fine.

How should I deal with the problem?

I worked around it by making the method synchronious and writing:

```
var keys = await secretManager.GetKeys().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Does anybody has a better truly async solution?

This boils down basically to async operations in Startup. I have other use cases, where I face the same problem: I would e.g. like to load some services based on Feature Flags, and getting those is an async operation again.

Comment: Get the keys beforehand ?

Comment: but where? This code has to run in Startup, and the whole Startup is synchronious

Comment: How about retrieving that certificate inside your `Program`'s `Main`? Since C# 7.1 the [main can be async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main). Or you can implement a custom `IHostedService`, which exposes `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0))

Comment: I don't think an `IHostedService` is needed here.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh Can you use the async Main to retrieve the certificate or are you looking for other alternative(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Not a truly async solution, but a better workaround:

I struggled with long startup times and got tired of it yesterday. A profiling revealed 30 seconds wait time on `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

There is a property `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` which can be used instead of `IssuerSigningKeys`. It's not async, but can be exploited to achieve the same result:

Call `secretManager.GetKeys()`, but do not wait for it. Assign the result somewhere. The task is started and will run in the background.

Move the waiting to the delegate. Immediate benefit is that your startup code no longer has to wait for the lookup. But your users will, if they are unlucky. The task will most likely finish before the first user arrives.

```
var keyLoader = secretManager.GetKeys(); // Move call to here

services
  .AddAuthentication()
  .AddJwtBearer(DomainConstants.MyAuthenticationScheme, async options =>
    {
       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
          IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (...) => // parameters may be ignored
          {
            var keys = await keyloader.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // wait for it
            var signingKeys = ...
            return signingKeys;
          },
          ...
        }
     });
```

My solution is more complex, but this is the essence of it.